# js files path in the right direction but not responding in the theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dynamic

I'm using a layer slider in my HTML site. When, I'm going to add this slider to a WordPress theme. It's not responding. Even, on the page view source the file path in the right direction. Why they aren't responding.

HTML code for the slider:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="assets/layerslider/layerslider.min3831.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="homeSliderWrapper">
  <div id="homeSliderInner" class="ls-bk-container" data-ride="make-layer-slider" data-id="1" data-version="1" data-src="assets/js/slider.js"></div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/layerslider/layerslider.min1ee01ee0.js?v=u_3YRY7JXqEPApYnTt38DqqTzw01kqG41N4v5Osr03Y1"></script>
```

Now when I make them to dynamic for Wordpress theme. Code for WP theme:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/layerslider/layerslider.min3831.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>For test.</h1>

 <div id="homeSliderWrapper">
  <div id="homeSliderInner" class="ls-bk-container" data-ride="make-layer-slider" data-id="1" data-version="1" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/js/slider.js"></div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/layerslider/layerslider.min1ee01ee0.js?v=u_3YRY7JXqEPApYnTt38DqqTzw01kqG41N4v5Osr03Y1"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

When I checked view source code, all files get the right path. But why isn't it responding?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress to make your assets work correctly you have to use the **functions.php** and create a function that registers and loads the assets scripts styles etc.

The following link has examples and also explains in detail how https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/